# How to use unirest-net properly on Discord

Tags: c#, .net, discord, unirest, discord.net

I want to `ReplyAsync` lyrics for a particular song so I used the unirest-net api. Here's how I use the command:

```
/// <summary> The lyric generating task </summary>
/// <returns> The <see cref="Task"/> </returns>
[Command("lyric")]
public async Task LyricTask()
{
    Task<HttpResponse<string>> response = Unirest.get("https://musixmatchcom-musixmatch.p.mashape.com/wsr/1.1/matcher.lyrics.get?q_artist=imagine+dragons&q_track=Battle+cry")
        .header("X-Mashape-Key", "secret_key")
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .asJsonAsync<string>();

    await this.ReplyAsync(response.ToString());
}
```

But I get the output `System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[unirest_net.http.HttpResponse1[System.String]]` always. What am i doing wrong and how do i make it work?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used `HttpResponse` before but after looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse(v=vs.110).aspx), I think you need to call [`Flush()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ToString()`.

From the `Flush()` documentation:

> Sends all currently buffered output to the client.

**Edit:** You have to call `Flush()` from the `Result` property of the `Task<HttpResult>` object:

`await this.ReplyAsync(response.Result.Flush());`

Comment: A task HttpResponse does not contain a definition for Flush.

Comment: Of course the `Task<HttpResponse>` doesn't have a definition for `Flush()`... The `HttpResponse` object has the `Flush()` method. You need to call `Flush()` from the [`Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the Task. `await this.ReplyAsync(response.Result.Flush());` I love that I'm downvoted because OP didn't know how to use tasks.

Comment: I'm sorry if you think that way but I am not the one who downvoted you.